# Is it possible to put `csproj.user` XML in `csproj` for version control?

Tags: xml, visual-studio, command-line-arguments, csproj

Everyone says thou shalt never add `*.csproj.user` to TFS for version control. Fine, but what if I want to specify default command line arguments (which get saved in the file mentioned above)?

I poked around the the `.csproj` file, and the XML looks very similar. So that got me thinking... Can you cut and paste the following XML from the `csproj.user` file to the end of the `csproj` file (just above the `</Project>` tag?

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU'">
  <StartArguments>..\..\DEALS001.ini</StartArguments>
</PropertyGroup>
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU'">
  <StartArguments>..\..\DEALS001.ini</StartArguments>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely! This works like a charm.

Do note that subsequent changes to the command line argument from the Visual Studio Project Properties window will create a new `csproj.user` file that would override (but not remove) the XML you copied to the `csproj` file.